# Next Button in Keyboard is not showing

Tags: android

I want when user type then instead of arrow key it should show the next button in keyboard.
So user not need to press the back to input next edittext.

Added the Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#D5D5D5"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/topLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dip"
        android:background="@drawable/bar" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/new_quote_imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/new_quote_bar" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contactUs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/contact_us"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dip" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight=".7"
                    android:background="#EEEBE6"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="15dip" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                        android:text="@string/name"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/nameEditText"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dip"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dip" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/emailTextView"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                        android:text="@string/email"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dip"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/commentsTextView"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                        android:text="@string/comments"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/commentsEditText"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                        android:lines="5" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                        android:weightSum="1" >

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/submitButton"
                            android:layout_width="0dip"
                            android:layout_height="35dip"
                            android:layout_weight=".3"
                            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
                            android:text="@string/submit"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please help me for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: would you post your xml layout

Comment: @MohammodHossain I have added the layout.Please see now

Comment: you should use `android:imeOption="actionNext`

Comment: @thepoosh Please let me know where should i use it..?

Comment: add as a edit text property

Comment: @thepoosh I used the `android:imeOption="actionNext` in the first name edittext. but still it showing the arrow key instead of next.

Comment: try to add android:singleLine="true" into edittext

Comment: add android:inputType="text"

Answer (score 16):

add this line to your edittext xml

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want multiple line simple add

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

else please use this given solution

```
                  <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/commentsEditText"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:lines="5" />
```

I have added

```
  android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

this line extra, use this in every EditText that you want have next button  in soft key Board

Comment: Yeah... Actually it  is not worked because you are using android:line="5" that means you can enter and add next line so by default  it is showing enter button ie. arrow.. Hope you are getting.

Answer (score 3):

Define inputType for each edit text.

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/editText"
     android:inputType="textPersonName" />
```

Comment: must be android:inputType="textPersonName" instead

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to the edit text:

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

android:singleLine="true" //deprecated

use android:maxLines="1" & imeOptions

```
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Simply use 
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
android:maxLines="1"

and remove if you have used digits.

android:digits
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in your edittext

```
android:imeOptions="flagNavigateNext"
```

Example given below:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/commentsEditText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:lines="5"             
        android:imeOptions="flagNavigateNext"/>
```

Comment: Still no next button ...Only arrow key.

Comment: both landscape and portrait layout?

Comment: Only on landscape its showing next but on portrait..there is not. I want it both.

Comment: I can not set the `android:singleLine="true". Because i need to show just textarea.

Comment: this is what client want..Please help me in that case.

Comment: Any solutions for this?

Comment: When i am using the ` android:inputType="text" ` then again it make my multi line editext to single line edittext.

Comment: its giving error message "Error: String type not allowed at android:imeOptions="IME_FLAG_NAVIGATE_NEXT"

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this

```
android:imeOptions="flagNavigateNext"
android:inputType="text"
```